# When my ViewController runs, a gradient background is on my iPhone but it appears fine in the simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

So I am running a simple ViewController in swift and it when I run it, on the simulator it looks fine but on my iPhone it doesn't.

Here is how the background looks like on the simulator(correctly)

[image: 1]: ![enter image description here] "simulator"

and here is when I run it on the iPhone

[image: 2]: ![enter image description here] "iPhone"

They are both just images that I uploaded (this includes the dividers, 'pounds', and 'repetitions' while the logo on top and button in the bottom are part of the window.

So because of this, I know the problem is in the background but I tried going setting by setting to compare them to other Views that do work and can't seem to find the answer. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you use the correct capitalization of the image name. I believe the simulator works with incorrect capitalization, but the device does not.

Comment: I checked and it all seems to have the same capitalization. The background image is showing because the pattern is there but the green fill isn't.